# Difference between JOIN and Inner JOIN in Sybase

Tags: sql, database, sybase

I have a query like below. I don't understand the difference between `join` vs `inner join` used on the below code. Aren't they the same? This is written for `Sybase`. Please help me know the difference.

```
SELECT
   count(distinct c.stuID ) as cnt 
FROM
   tableC c 
   Inner Join
      tableB b 
      On c.otherID = b.otherID 
   Inner Join
      tableX gd 
      On b.otherID = gd.otherID 
   Inner Join
      tableY g 
      On gd.groupID = g.GROUPID 
      and g.GROUPTYPEID in 
      (
         1,
         3
      )
   JOIN
      tableZ d 
      on c.OPID = d.OPID 
   JOIN
      tableM e 
      on c.OTHERID = e.otherID 
      and c.stuID = e.stuID 
      and DATEDIFF(..........)
```

Comment: There is no difference.  They are synonyms.

Comment: They are functionally equivalent, but `INNER JOIN` can be a bit clearer to read, particularly if the query has other join types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the standard INNER JOIN=JOIN. I think, Sybase does not break this rule